# Prevent Catalina from asking for app permissions (like microphone or keychain access) on each new Xcode build

Tags: xcode, macos, permissions, keychain, macos-catalina

It seems that Catalina will ask the user for permissions for an app every time anything changes in the Xcode build.

For example, I have a simple example that asks for permission to access the microphone.  The first time the app is compiled and run, it asks for microphone access.  I grant that access.  If I build and run again without changing anything in the code, that access will be retained.  However, if I change any code (even changing the `Text` label by one character), the permission dialog is displayed again.

```
import AVFoundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @ObservedObject private var recorderManager = AudioRecorderManager()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Recording view")
    }
}

class AudioRecorderManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    override init() {
        super.init()

        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .audio) { allowed in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if allowed {
                    print("Allowed")
                } else {
                    print("Not allowed")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Note that this also requires you to add `Audio Input` to the entitlements and `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` to the `Info.plist` before it'll run.***

I've also noticed the same phenomenon happening with accessing `Keychain` data.

This is dramatically slowing down my development time having to confirm access (or worse, enter my password for the Keychain data) every single time I build the app.  Is there a solution to get Catalina/Xcode to give lasting permission to the app during development?

Comment: Code sign your build

Comment: @TheNextman Wow -- I had no idea the fix was that simple.  To be fair, my app was "Signed to run locally," but not signed for "Development".  How frustrating!  Thanks you -- would be happy to accept the answer as correct if left as an answer instead of a comment.